Can't upgrade firmware -- fwupd fails to start
I have a Thinkpad T470s running Pop_OS 22.04 and since I got it a year ago, I haven't been able to do any firmware upgrades as fwupd fails to start.
When I run sudo systemctl status fwupd I get:
× fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fwupd.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2024-04-14 08:06:04 CDT; 2min 37s ago
       Docs: https://fwupd.org/
    Process: 6354 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 6354 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
        CPU: 766ms

Apr 14 08:03:04 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Apr 14 08:03:04 pop-os fwupd[6354]: 13:03:04.368 FuEngine             no GUIDs for device TPM [***REDACTED***]
Apr 14 08:06:04 pop-os systemd[1]: fwupd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 14 08:06:04 pop-os systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 14 08:06:04 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start Firmware update daemon.

The problem seems to be related to the FuEngine error.
Things I've tried:

Reset the Bios
Reinstalling fwupd using apt

Other possibly related problems:
On boot, I have always gotten a brief error reading FW Downgrade - Request MeSpiLock
